# Detecting changes in distribution of multiple variables

Tags: machine-learning, change-point

I am a bit new to this field. So I needed help in finding out which topic should I focus on for achieving this.

Suppose I have N dependent random variables. I have n samples of each of these random variables.
Now I want to check if the kth sample follows the pattern that is suggested by the previous (k-1) samples.

For example if there are 2 variables - X1 and X2. For the first 10 samples lets say X1 > X2. But if for the next sample X1 < X2, then this sample is anomalous. I need to detect such an anomalous sample.

Can you tell me what statistical machine learning concepts should I study in order to understand which techniques are applicable in such a scenario?

From my limited knowledge this appears to be a classification problem that must be attacked with unsupervised technique.

Comment: I find the question too vague. You need to define "anomalous", e.g. as you did in the example. In statistics terms, you need to define a model for "normality" (i.e. lack of abnormality)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the [Mahalanobis Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance). You would apply this by estimating the population covariance and mean vector using the previous $(k-1)$ samples (assuming $k > N$, where $N$ is the dimension of your observed vectors), and then computing the Mahalanobis Distance. A google search reveals a lot of hits on this topic, [Bartkowiak](http://www.ibib.waw.pl/bbe/bbefulltext/BBE_25_1_007_FT.pdf) seems like a decent starting place.

Comment: I tried calculating with a contrived dataset having 100 samples drawn from a hypergeometric distribution. The dimension was 6. I get the following error in R:

> mahalanobis(x=c(28, 22, 3, 20, 4, 2), mean1, cov1)
Error in solve.default(cov, ...) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.16688e-018

Comment: It works for me: `mean1 <- c(0,0,2,3,4,1)
cov1 <- cov(matrix(rnorm(200*6),ncol=6))
mahalanobis(c(28,22,3,20,4,2),center=mean1,cov=cov1)`
Maybe your covariance _is_ singular? check with `rcond(cov1)` (should give a reasonably small number)

Comment: yes it does give a small number.

Comment: mat1 = t(rMWNCHypergeo(100, m=c(10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 10000000),  n=10000, odds=c(30, 20, 10, 30, 5, 5)));
cov1 = cov(mat1);
mean1 = c(mean(mat1[,1]), mean(mat1[,2]), mean(mat1[,3]), mean(mat1[,4]), mean(mat1[,5]), mean(mat1[,6]));

I used Hypergeometric distribution. What should we do when the cov matrix is singular?

Comment: I get a _very_ small number when I look at the `rcond(cov(mat1))` using your example `mat1`, like 1e-17. Your covariance is rank 5, so any techniques which invert it are going to fail. Looking at `rowSums(mat1)` I see the problem: the columns of `mat1` are _not_ linearly independent--they all sum to 10000. This is probably due to how your Hypergeometric generation process works (_i.e._ each ball drawn has to be from _some_ class). To get around this problem, subselect the first five columns of `mat1` and ignore the last one (it is completely determined by the first five). hth.

Comment: This does seem to work. I tried giving points which were approximately similar to the ones in the dataset. I get a low value for this distance. Anything unusual causes this to shoot up. I have  a few questions though:
1. This measure seems to be somewhat dated. Have better techniques been since then? I can imagine updating the covariance matrix, mean as each sample comes in and flagging the sample as anomalous when the distance is too higher than a threshold.

Comment: 2. Can this or some other technique be modified to point out the defaulting variable? It is possible that there is only one variable that is causing the imbalance. I am thinking on the lines of mainting marginal mean, covariance matrices as in mean, covariance matrix of $ 5 \choose 4 $ combinations of variables. Is that the correct way?

Answer (score 5):

This sounds to me more like a change point problem. You should investigate the bcp package, http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bcp/index.html, as well as strucchange, http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/strucchange/index.html

John Emerson maintains the bcp package, and when I met him, he seemed very willing to engage the community and potential users: john.emerson at yale.edu

Alternatively, if your data are time series data, you may wish to investigate the qcc package, and read some of Douglas Montgomery's work on Statistical Quality Control.